# Is there a way to access the Bing Maps geocoding API via REST?

Tags: google-maps, maps, geocoding, bing-maps, yahoo-maps

Is there a way to access the Bing Maps API via REST to obtain geocoding information from an address?  This is something that's trivial to do with Google and Yahoo; what I'm looking for is functionality like this, from Yahoo:

http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html

(Specifically, see the sample request URL on that page, but also imagine that URL with a simple "location" parameter rather than separate street, city, state, and zip parameters.)

I've found examples of using other parts of the Bing API via REST, but nothing that accesses the Maps API, or specifically, the geocoding functionality.

Comment: Their XML Response DTD published anywhere? http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1 redirects to an error page!

Comment: There is a new API from Yahoo which replaces the one you mentioned: http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently, there now is a Bing Maps REST API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

Comment: Lookie there -- they finally added one!

Comment: "Copyright © 2018 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation."

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with codes...
http://zachsgeospatial.blogspot.com/2011/05/geocoding-via-bing-maps-rest-api.html
I hope it will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the SOAP client is the only one provided to access the geocoding service. I was expecting a REST access too because yahoo and google allow that, but I didn't find anything about it.
Note however that I didn't find anything mentioning it wasn't possible to access the Bing Maps web services via REST, so there may be one....

Answer (score -2):

Use the Bing Maps Geocode Service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966793.aspx

Comment: Um, nope, Shawn -- that's a SOAP web service, not REST.  As I explained in the question, I'm looking for REST.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking you could wrap the SOAP web service with a REST API

Comment: (No offense meant, really, but I'm not sure how I could have intuited that intention from your response...)